# Logging SqlCommand only in case of error w/ PetaPoco

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, petapoco

I know I can log exceptions with PetaPoco thus:

```
public override void OnException(Exception x)
{
    _logger.LogError(x);
}
```

I also realize I can dump the command text + params:

```
public override void OnExecutingCommand(System.Data.IDbCommand cmd)
{
    _logger.LogInfo(cmd.CommandText);
    foreach (SqlParameter sqlParam in cmd.Parameters)
    {
        _logger.LogInfo(String.Format("Name: {0}; Value: {1}; SqlValue: {1}", sqlParam.ParameterName,
                                      sqlParam.Value, sqlParam.SqlValue));
    }
    base.OnExecutingCommand(cmd);
}
```

Naturally, I don't really want to log each command+params in a production environment.

What's the best approach to log the command + params **only** when an exception is thrown?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
public override void OnException(Exception x)
{
    _logger.Log(LastCommand);
    _logger.LogError(x);
}
```

`LastSql` and `LastArgs` are also available.